# Bootstrap navbar text/buttons are half way down the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jekyll

I am using the below code in a header to provide a fixed bootstrap navbar:

```
<header class="site-header">

<a class="site-title" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">{{ site.title }}</a>

    <!-- START NAVBAR/HEADER -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://xxxx.github.io">Your Name</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="http://xxxx.github.io/pages/About.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://xxxx.github.io/pages/Blog.html">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://xxxx.github.io/pages/Contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/VitamnD"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="https://instagram.com/vitamnd/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/xxxx"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com/in/yourname/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR -->
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

.intro-text {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
}

.full-width-image-1 {
    background: url(../img/lake.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 100px 0;
    height: 500px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 100;
}

.full-width-image-2 {
    background: url(../img/watercabin.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    height: 450px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
}

.logo-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.name {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
}

.section {
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}

.section-heading {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.home-heading {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    margin: 30px 0;
    color: #000;
}

.section-lead {
    margin: 30px 0;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #333;
}

.section-paragraph {
    margin: 30px 0;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 

}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

.section-heading {
    font-size: 4em;
}

.section {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header .container {
        padding: 200px 0 100px;
    }

    header .intro-text .name {
        font-size: 4em;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    header .intro-text .skills {
        font-size: 1.75em;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
}

.full-width-image-1 .intro-text {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-size: 2em;
}

.full-width-image-1 .intro-text .name {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    color: #FFF;
}

header .intro-text .name {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.centered-text {
    text-align:center
}

.align-right {
    text-align: right
}

.glyphicon.bigger {font-size: 30px;}

.social {
   padding-right: 12px;
}

.container .row .col-lg-12.section .lead.section-lead {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

This code works great on an earlier iteration of my basic site:
http://xxxx.github.io

However I am now adding this code to a header.html file in order to migrate to Jekyll.

In this case it produces a fat navbar, with the text and buttons half way down the page as can be seen in the attached screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/akmtoy3vgoecqgt/Screenshot%202014-09-26%2022.35.50.png?dl=0

If a navbar height is added to the CSS, the navbar height changes but the buttons stay in the same location:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ss2y0ztzn4entui/Screenshot%202014-09-26%2022.16.18.png?dl=0

Comment: Please show your css, since it works fine with your html and bootstrap css: http://jsfiddle.net/haa76q5h/

Comment: Further details added.

Comment: Have you tried using developer tools in whichever browser you're using to examine the navbar to see if additional CSS styling is being applied?

Comment: I dont see any issues. Even going to your site, and editing the live content with what you provided gave no issues. Perhaps you are viewing an old cached version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what messes it up:

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
   header .container {
      padding: 200px 0 100px;
   }
}
```

Makes no sense to me :)

Comment: Yes seems to have fixed the issue, thanks. Although it has messed up some font size elsewhere! I'll figure it out anyway, thanks.